# Taking random value as duration in animate function of JQuery

Tags: jquery

In my code,I have used 1000 ms as the duration value in animate function.Now I want to use a random value in place of this value.How can I do so?

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btn').click(function () {
$('#i1').animate({
'margin-left': '+=1155px'
},1000);
});
</script>
<img src="images.jpg" height="100px" width="200px" id="i1"><br>
<input type="button" value="start" id="btn">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try something ? What was the problem ?

Comment: look at Math.random()

Comment: Google before you ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple as this as I think.

Use

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
```

Where *100 is the maximum value to be generated.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function( $ ){ // Dom ready shorthand
  $('#btn').click(function () {
      $('#i1').animate({
        'margin-left': '+=1155px'
      }, Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1) );
  });
});
</script>
```

If you need to reuse your *random* on more places you can have some fun with your own reusable methods:

```
var MM = { // My Methods
   rand : function(min,max) { // RANDOMIZER
       return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
   },  // comma separate 
   something : function() {
       // return your other method
   }
}
```

and use like `MM.rand( minValue , maxValue);`

```
$('#i1').animate({marginLeft: '+=1155'}, MM.rand(200, 1000) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generate the random number in place as **duration** parameter of `amimate()` function
then your code become

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btn').click(function () {
$('#i1').animate({
'margin-left': '+=1155px'
},Math.floor((Math.random()*2000)+1000));
});
```

here generate the random number between 1000 and 2000.